# Tags with special Latin characters don't work well

Tags: bug, tags

When editing a question that has a tag containing special Latin characters (such as *gramática*), at least in the mobile site (Chrome,  Android), the letter with diacritic is replaced with it's symbolic representation (I think HTML), in this case it was *á*. Then, when I submit the edit, it complains this is not a valid tag, so I have to retype it. Can this be fixed?

The same happens in the mobile app, when searching, but it does work properly, otherwise.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to use tag synonyms (but for that we best need a moderator, or at least a handful of users with 1250 or more), so that you can type & use `gramatica` and the tag applied & displayed will be `gramática`. (We have the same problem with macrons, as in ō, on Japanese.SE.)

Comment: That would work too

Comment: Soon someone has to go through all those tags, name them properly and create tag synonyms. It's becoming a mess =)

Comment: It is indeed... Problem being that there are so many already

Comment: @Earthliŋ If/when someone takes on that task, I hope they draw attention to it on meta so we can help vote on their proposed synonyms. On SO, I posted suggesting that "subset" and "subsetting" were synonyms, and it took a year to go through...

Comment: @Frank Moderators can create tag synonyms, there's no need to vote. This site will have moderators in a few weeks, in the meantime you can ask JNat. On [french.se], we routinely create tag synonyms: French name, French name without accents, English name. Requests can be made in chat, there's no need for a formal process.

Comment: @Gilles Okay, thanks for the pointers. That simplifies the process a lot.

Comment: P.S. You can use [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/portuguese/query/205529/tag-names-with-non-ascii-characters-diacritics-etc) to find tag names with diacritics that may be missing a synonym. And [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/portuguese/query/205664/tags-with-no-synonym) may help locate tags that lack a transaction. The pages don't work yet because Portuguese.SE isn't in the database, it'll be added in a couple of weeks, in the meantime you can see them at play by replacing `portuguese` by e.g. `french` in the URL.

Comment: @someonewithpc Sorry, typo: *translation*.

Comment: By the way, did you experience this bug on the desktop site, or on a mobile device? If it's on the main site, with which browser? If it's mobile, which OS? I know that on the desktop site, we have no problems with accents on [french.se]. The mobile app, on the other hand, is quite buggy once you go beyond the basics.

Comment: @Gilles It's _meant_ to say that in the questions, so I'm gonna blame the autocorrect